# Cause and prevention of post-race headache

Tags: running

I often get a mild headache within a few hours of finishing a half marathon race or other intense distance run. I otherwise feel fine. Are there any common causes of/methods to prevent such headaches? I drink water during such runs regularly but in moderation, only as I feel thirst, and I eat plenty of the standard finish-line fare. I don't get these headaches after shorter or less intense runs.

I found [a similar question on this site](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/11920/cold-and-fever-after-doing-extensive-cardio-sport), and am not certain whether my question would be considered a duplicate or not (I'm talking only a mild headache with no other symptoms or signs of reduced immune response).

Comment: I do think it a dup, though your case is not as severe :-) For reference, I usually drink approx 1l/15km post-race - usually apple juice, cacao and similar

Comment: My experience: I only get a headache when I'm underhydrated, and for me 20+ km distances require more water per km than shorter ones.  Will you get headaches if you drink, say, twice as much water?